# Add sequencing in Selenoid

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, selenoid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Nyq.png)

I'm currently running automation script on Selenoid. My testcase currently is failing. I have attached the screenshot where the expected output is different from the current output. I need to add sequencing in the code.

Below is the code snippet:

```java
test(() -> jsApi().insertText(TextOptions.subtitle().setContent("Foo\nBar")))

@Override
protected List<Runnable> testSteps() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            wrapStep(0, () -> edit().setSeparatorPeriod()),
            wrapStep(1, () -> edit().setSeparatorParenthesis()),
            wrapStep(1, () -> edit().setSeparatorDash()),
            wrapStep(1, () -> edit().setSeparatorSpace())
    );
}
```

I'm new to Selenoid automation, and I'm not sure how to add sequencing in the above code snippet.

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
11:11:32.457 [INFO] Comparing images: Different content
11:11:32.958 [ERROR] Didn't get expected view after 10000 ms of waiting
11:11:32.961 [ERROR] Screenshot 0: Different content
11:11:33.582 [ERROR] Screenshot 1: Different content
```

How do I add sequencing to the code and what I'm thinking is the correct issue or is there some other problem with the code?

Comment: Selenoid itself is just a synchronous API that executes every command in browser that you send to it. So this issue is not related to the server-side infrastructure at all and seems to be an issue in your code.